# can't generate ctags python

Tags: python, vim, ctags, completion

I am in `myproject/src/python/` which contains sub-multiple packages with (obviously) python source code.

Running `ctags -a -R .` generates a large `tags` file inside `myproject/src/python/`

Now (I am inside `myproject/src/python/` ) I am doing `vim packageName/module.py`. I have a class called `class Derived(Whatever)`. When I try to have the definition of `Whatever`, Vim tells me `tag not found`. However, when I do `cat myproject/src/python/tags | grep Whatever`, I can find it.

```
$ ctags --version
Exuberant Ctags 5.8, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Feb 12 2019, 19:25:46
  Addresses: <dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net>, http://ctags.sourceforge.net
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex
```

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

P.S. Also, the coode-completion on an object doesn't work well, it just gives me the whole list with all possible members, functions, and classes; instead of giving only members available on this particular object

Answer (score 0):

Might it be, that you have `autochdir` set?

Try:

```
:set tags=tags;
```

The semicolon at the end means, that it should search in parent dirs if there is no file `tags` in the current directory.

See `:help 'tags'` and `:help file-searching`.